# Google Ad exchange and detecting no targeted Adverts

Tags: javascript, iframe, backup, google-dfp

We are using Google DoubleClick Ad exchange (https://www.google.com/adx/) for targeted adverts for a customer, What I am after is a way to find out or detect that no targeted adverts were available for display on a page with multiple adverts. I have setup backup adverts (https://support.google.com/adxseller/answer/1262285?hl=en) but because they are within iFrames on another domain I cannot Access the contents of the iFrame to determine the image (the backup image) that is returned. The goal is to allow our customer to be able to on the client-side to know if no targeted advert was available and replace it with an alternative random image of theirs? Is their anything in the Google Ad exchange API or response that can be used on the client-side to identify this response?

Thanks in advance.

Mo

Answer (score 0):

You tagged this question with google-dfp, if you are using DFP then then solving this problem is trivial. Just setup a line-item for AdX for the required ad units and set a floor-price in AdX. Setup another line-item which fills all the impressions that AdX didn't take an put the random images in that line item.

Another way to solve this (without using an ad server) is setting up a backup HTML page instead of a backup image. This backup HTML page can be dynamically generated to output the random image that your client wants to show. You can also use this HTML page to run some JavaScript to collapse the ad-unit and trigger something on the parent page.

Comment: In terms of using a HTML page, using JavaScript how can you identify which of the adverts from the multiple on the page is the ad slot that has not returned any adverts, i.e. which iFrame to delete or hide from the DOM

Comment: When using DFP you can ask DFP to collapse the divs that are not filled with a creative. DFP also has a callback which enables you to replace the collapsed divs with a random image (or do whatever you want). When using a pure AdX solution the backup HTML page can collapse the div/iframe itself. The iframes that are used by Google are Friendly iframes which enable JS in the iframe to access the parent page.